# How to get only one studentid which has same studentid and get all related data of studentid in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

How to get only one studentid which has same studentid and get all related data of studentid in laravel?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot looks like a MySQL database. Do you need an SQL command like `group by` ?

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code.

Comment: When i search studentid then data related studentid should be fetch and then
what i want is related studentid(you can see there are three same studentid 5) among
them only show 1 studentid (like display 5 only) but show all related their values like yearid(3,3,3), date(2071-07-11,2071-07-12,2071-07-13),attendance(1,1,1)